# Flow execution logging in django-vieflow

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

How can I track process/task execution in viewflow with logger?

In the [docs](https://django-viewflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_concepts.html) is mentioned:

> In case if you need to track some execution info or add logging, you can do it by extending viewflow.models.Task

I could not find any example or more detailed documentation for logging in django-viewflow though.

Comment: The actual docs at the http://docs.viewflow.io/

Answer (score 1):

The task models itself tracks all flow execution history and timestamps. If you need an additional info you could store it inside task.data JSON field